# QCoreApplication::processEvents - why must it be called from main thread only?

Tags: c++, qt, event-loop, qeventloop

Since there is only one `QCoreApplication` object, why does it matter from which thread `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` is called?

After all, the threads all share the same address space.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... `processEvents()` docs say: _Calling this function processes events only for the calling thread._  So if it didn't matter which thread it was called from... it couldn't do its job?  Or are you asking how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title is not true. Probably you are assuming `QCoreApplication::processEvents` is a system-wide "process all possible events of all threads" call, which it is not. You can call it from any thread you are in (and which is running an event loop).

Why does it matter from which thread it is called: In Qt the event loop is a per-thread resource (you can run own event loop on any thread) and `QCoreApplication::processEvents` processes event queue of the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this warning it is because code inside the `processEvents` is not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).  Even though they share the same address space, work or data could be accumulated in a state on one thread, then the thread may be interrupted, the state could be modified by another thread, and then the original thread will resume its process as if the original state was still valid, but now it isn't.  You could lose data or corrupt memory if you were doing things like modifying a linked list or any non-threadsafe data structure, among other hazards.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I'll wait a few hours before accepting the answer.

Comment: It claims right in the [processEvents docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) that it is, indeed, thread-safe.Although this is a good concise explanation of thread safety, so I'm loath to down-vote :)